# Merge [fhir] and [hl7-fhir]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

HL7 is simply the organisation responsible for the FHIR spec. As such, there's no difference in meaning between [hl7-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-fhir) and [fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir) and the two should be merged.

My first instinct was to keep [fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir), since the prefix seems gratuitous; we don't generally prefix technology names with the names of their creators in tags.

However, two reasons we might want to do the opposite direction:

- [hl7-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-fhir) is much more popular
- As Gimby points out in the comments, the predecessors to FHIR - namely, HL7 messaging v2 and v3 - are referenced by the tags [hl7-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-v2) and [hl7-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-v3) - so using [hl7-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-fhir) would maintain consistency of naming across the specs.

I'm not too fussed what direction the merge happens in; I just want it to happen in *some* direction rather than keep the tags erroneously distinct.

Comment: Hm. I'm on the fence. hl7-fhir may seem superfluous, but fhir is a followup to the HL7v2 and HL7v3 specs, on stackoverflow referenced by the tags hl7-v2 and hl7-v3. The naming convention makes sense from a tag perspective.

Comment: Checked the questions that have just one of the two tags, all of them refer to the same FHIR. Synonymized for now. Also yay! An acronym that's not used for two different things.

Comment: @BhargavRao I'm not too familiar with the tag system, but isn't it best practice to basically always merge instead of just synonymising? This way leaves behind a weird zombie tag that can't be used on new questions but is still present on some old ones and still shows up as a separate tag in the tagging dialog.

Comment: We wait for 3 days~1 week and see if anyone has any issues... if not, we merge.

Comment: @BhargavRao Seems like it should now be merge time, then?

Comment: Aye, have some syns on my list which have to be merged... I was busy last weekend due to some personal work, so thinking of doing it this weekend. Sorry bout that.

Comment: @MarkAmery Could use some feedback [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411060/merging-the-fhir-tags) if you get a chance. Thanks