# Merging the FHIR tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Related loosely to [Merge [fhir] and [hl7-fhir]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376290/merge-fhir-and-hl7-fhir)

I ran across a fairly specific tag wiki entry, but the tag seemed too specific. After some poking around, I found a number of tags that were too granular to warrant their own tag (like [fhir-questionnaire], [javascript-fhir], etc). I merged them with [hl7-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-fhir)

There's still some tags that look redundant or granular

- [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7) - [48 questions overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhl7%5D+%5Bhl7-fhir%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3)
- [smart-on-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-on-fhir)
- [node-fhir-server-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-fhir-server-core)
- [fhir-server-for-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir-server-for-azure)
- [fhir-net-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir-net-api)

Keep these? Merge? Discussion and feedback encouraged

Comment: As a mod, is there a way for you to ping few users from Top Users for [tag:hl7]? Many of them are not much active on tag recently. Lloyd McKenzie is active but I never seen them on meta. So, it is less likely they see this meta post without ping.

Comment: hl7 seems redundant in general, there is no real need to ask anything as generic as that. You either have a question about hl7v2, hl7v3 or fhir, they're all very different beasts.

Comment: @AmitJoshi Yes, in case you're simply asking if mods *can* do that; they can super ping users to notify them somewhere. However, you can also notify a user via ping by commenting under any of their posts or replying to any comments they've made :-)

Comment: @AmitJoshi I think there's enough other commentary about [hl7] to leave it

Comment: HL7 should absolutely not be merged with FHIR. They're two totally different formats (as someone who has briefly worked on an EMR integration team that handles this kind of stuff in Corepoint).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I found a number of tags that were too granular to warrant their own tag (like [fhir-questionnaire], [javascript-fhir], etc)

That sounds like it was the right thing to do (though I can't see the old tag descriptions now so maybe I'm missing something). In particular, we don't need tags for the intersection of a programming language and some other concept; a `javascript-fhir` tag seems as arbitrary to me as if we were to have `javascript-json` or `python-xml` or `java-long-polling`. People whose question relates to two orthogonal concepts should just use two tags.

However, I think all the other tags you're suggesting merging should be kept. Some commentary:

> There's still some tags that look redundant or granular
>
> - [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7) - [48 questions overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhl7%5D+%5Bhl7-fhir%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3)

I would keep this.

Depending on how people interpret the tag, [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7) is either strictly broader in scope than FHIR, or simply completely *different* in scope and mostly orthogonal. The FHIR standard is published by HL7 (the organisation), referred to on hl7.org as a "HL7 standard", and borrows/inherits some of the concepts and names in its object model from older HL7 standards; as such you could sort of conceive of [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7) as encompassing FHIR and think of [hl7-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-fhir) tag as being analogous to a version-specific language tag like [python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python3). *However*, the older HL7 standards that were simply named "HL7" (or more specifically things like "HL7 Version 2") differ from FHIR in two pretty drastic ways:

- FHIR messages are encoded in JSON or XML, while HL7 messages use a hideous unreadable proprietary format that uses `|` and `^` characters as delimiters.
- FHIR has (from what I can tell from browsing hl7.org a bit) a much deeper and more complicated ontology of concepts that HL7 does. For example, compare the way that allergies are described in HL7 v2 (in [an AL1 segment](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.3/Segments/AL1)) with how they are described in FHIR (in an [AllergyIntolerance resource](http://hl7.org/fhir/allergyintolerance.html)). The latter model has the ability to represent loads of extra information, like a history of reactions the patient has had along with their times and exposure routes and the severity of each reaction. That stuff simply isn't representable in the analogous HL7 segment.

Whatever you conceive of the scope of [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7) as being, I don't think it makes much sense to merge the two tags. Most people who follow [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7) probably do so because they've used something like HL7 Version 2, and that won't give them much expertise in dealing with FHIR questions, nor vice versa. If the standard you've used has a drastically different message encoding format *and* a drastically different taxonomy of medical concepts to the one being asked about in somebody's question, then what exactly is the value of the experience you're bringing to the table?

> - [node-fhir-server-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-fhir-server-core)
> - [fhir-server-for-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir-server-for-azure)
> - [fhir-net-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir-net-api)

I would keep all of these too, simply because they're tags for specific libraries, and I think tags that identify specific libraries and tools should be allowed to exist even if they're very niche (as these obviously are - they're libraries relating to a standard that itself only has a few hundred questions).

That said, the tag description for [fhir-server-for-azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir-server-for-azure) sucks - it describes the tag as being for *"Questions on implementing "Fast Healthcare Interoperability Resources" (FHIR) Server on Microsoft Azure platform."* That's dumb, for two reasons:

1. We shouldn't *have* a tag for the concept specified in the description; once again it's just an arbitrary intersection-of-two-concepts tag, like `javascript-fhir`.
2. Whoever originally made the tag presumably intended it to describe [*FHIR Server for Azure*](https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server), the Microsoft product whose name word-for-word matches the name of the tag.

I suggest that we change the tag description to refer specifically to *FHIR Server for Azure*, then look over the 45 questions that use the tag and retag any that *aren't* specifically about *FHIR Server for Azure* (which may be the majority of them - I haven't checked).

> [smart-on-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-on-fhir)

I'm least sure about this one because I don't have a very clear idea on what *SMART on FHIR* even *is*, to be honest. The tag description on Stack Overflow says it's a "platform" but on the SMART Health IT site they variously refer to it as a "protocol" (e.g. at http://docs.smarthealthit.org/client-py/) or an "open, free and standards-based API" (e.g. https://smarthealthit.org/). It seems like it's some kind of standard but I don't really know what it adds on top of the foundation that FHIR provides.

Regardless, though, it does seem to be a distinct standard from FHIR, with its own set of libraries. I figure it might as well have its own tag, too, but I'm basing that on my first-glance understanding of what *SMART on FHIR* is so I'd welcome confirmation on this one from somebody who knows what they're talking about!

Comment: My thinking has roughly been the same (I didn't mention [hapi-fhir] or [dstu2-fhir] for the same reasons you outlined above). You can see a full list of [synonyms I made](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hl7-fhir/synonyms) (except [fhir], which was made from the original request you made). I also synonymed [hapi-fhir-android-library] for being intersectional (HAPI is a Java library and can be joined with [android] easily enough). Good commentary on the other tags!

Comment: SMART on FHIR is a very specific subset. While FHIR is a more general protocol and format to exchange healthcare data, SMART on FHIR is really more of an SSO protocol that also uses FHIR for two applications to exchange information about the healthcare data a user is actively working with while also handling the SSO handoff. It should remain its own tag.

Comment: Note, there are some library implementations that may use their own tags https://confluence.hl7.org/display/FHIR/Open+Source+Implementations

Comment: A further detail found when I started looking into retagging: the "FHIR from Microsoft" section at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/healthcare-apis/fhir/overview lists three distinct FHIR-related Microsoft products. They probably deserve their own tags, which we can seed by retagging mistagged `fhir-server-for-azure` questions.

Answer (score 3):

About the tags you already merged, that seems correct step.

The [fhir-questionnaire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir-questionnaire): Questionnaire is [one of the resources](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/questionnaire.html) of FHIR. We do not create tag for each resource (the way we do not create tag for each class in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)).

The [javascript-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript-fhir): Again, we do not need separate tag for combination of specifications with each technology. Instead, [hl7-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-fhir) can be used in combination with specific technology ([javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) in this case).

About the tags you have requested inputs:

The [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7): This should stay as is. I do not think one need to combine [fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fhir) or [hl7-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7-fhir) with [hl7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hl7). But, this tag have very different usage with older versions of specifications i.e. v2 and v3. Although we also have specific tags for those versions, keeping the specifications tag still makes more sense as we do same with many technologies.

Rest of the tags except [smart-on-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-on-fhir) you mentioned seems like toolkit tags. IMO, those should not be merged.

About [smart-on-fhir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/smart-on-fhir), I do not have much understanding, so I will not make any comment on that.